# self-compile opencv, module cv2 has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

Tags: python, compilation, opencv

System information (version)

 4.2
- Operating System / Platform => Windows 64 Bit
- Compiler => Visual Studio 2017
-->

- OpenCV => :3.4.7:
- Operating System / Platform => :jetson nano ubuntu18.04 cuda10.0:
- Compiler => : nvcc 10.0 
  gcc 7.5.0
- Cannot install opencv from pip because of jetson nano using arm architecture

  ### Detailed description

I build opencv with the following instructions:

```
cmake   -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
        -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="5.3" \
        -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX="5.3" \
        -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON \
        -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON \
        -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON \
        -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
        -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
        -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON \
        -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
        -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
        -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF  \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-3.4.7/modules \
        -D WITH_TBB=ON \
        -D BUILD_opencv_world=OFF \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D WITH_GTK_2_X=ON \
        -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
        -D EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include/eigen3" \
        -D WITH_XINE=ON \
        -D WITH_GDAL=ON \
        -D WITH_QT=ON \
        ..
```

I really build the xfeatures2d:
[image]
But when I use `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` in python, it said `module 'cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'`

#### Steps to reproduce

I use the example from opencv: [Feature Matching + Homography to find Objects](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html)

```py
img1 = cv.imread('box.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv.imread('box_in_scene.png',0) # trainImage
# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
```

### build information

```py
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

```sh
General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.7 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/nvidia/Downloads/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.4.7/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-03-23T06:49:46Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.9.140-tegra aarch64
    CMake:                       3.10.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    NEON FP16
      required:                  NEON
      disabled:                  VFPV3

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.5.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          m pthread /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so cudart_static -lpthread dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppicom nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cufft -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 reg rgbd saliency sfm shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj hdf java js matlab ovis python2 ts viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.9.5)
      QT OpenGL support:         YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.9.5)
    GTK+:                        NO
    OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so)
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    GDAL:                        NO
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.107.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.83.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.78.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.8.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.7.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES
      base:                      YES (ver 1.14.5)
      video:                     YES (ver 1.14.5)
      app:                       YES (ver 1.14.5)
      riff:                      YES (ver 1.14.5)
      pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.14.5)
    libv4l/libv4l2:              1.14.2 / 1.14.2
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
    Xine:                        YES (ver 1.2.8)

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2017.0 interface 9107)

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      YES (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcblas.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libatlas.so)
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.4)
    Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.0, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             53
    NVIDIA PTX archs:            53

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/nvidia/Downloads/opencv/opencv-3.4.7/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.9)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.9)
    numpy:                       /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.18.1)
    install path:                lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
```

### cv2 submodules

Here is submodules, no xfeatures2d

```sh
SUBMODULES
    Error
    aruco
    bgsegm
    bioinspired
    cuda
    datasets
    detail
    dnn
    face
    fisheye
    flann
    freetype
    ft
    hfs
    img_hash
    instr
    ipp
    line_descriptor
    linemod
    ml
    motempl
    multicalib
    ocl
    ogl
    omnidir
    optflow
    plot
    ppf_match_3d
    reg
    rgbd
    saliency
    samples
    structured_light
    text
    utils
    videoio_registry
    videostab
    ximgproc
    xphoto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIFT is not supported in `opencv-python`. You need to install `opencv-contrib-python`.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```

Comment: I use the nvidia jetson nano, I cannot install cv2 from pip.